# Can I set up a Google Analytics view that filters out anyone with a user-id tagged on them?

Tags: google-analytics, users, filtering

I want to see all traffic and keep track of conversions until I add a user-id field to them?

So, if a user has a user-id tagged on them, they should be excluded in the view. However, I want all their data.

Comment: When you say you "want all their data", that means you want to have it on hand for other views, as opposed to somehow incorporated into the view without them?

Answer (score 1):

If you are capturing the user-id and sending it as a user scoped custom dimension, then you will be able to apply a filter to a View to exclude the users assigned a value for that particular custom dimension.

In doing this, any data before they are assigned a user-id and have it applied as a custom dimension will remain in the reports.